# p:hover::after/::before smooth transition

Tags: html, css, css-transitions

I am creating a Grid gallery.
Under each `img` I have `p` with a short name of a picture.

```html
<div id="projects-grid">
  <figure class="project-tile">
    <a href="">
      <img src="Portfolio_project_img_1.png" alt="">
      <p>Tribute Page</p>
    </a>
  </figure>
</div>
```

Before and after each `p` I need these characters to appear when hovering over `p`: "<" - before; "/>" - after
I need this transition to be smooth, like `ease-in-out, 0.3s`

I currently have this CSS code:

```css
#projects-grid p:hover::after {
  content: " />";
  font-size: 1.1rem;
  vertical-align: baseline;
  color: orange;
}
#projects-grid p:hover::before {
  content: "< ";
  font-size: 1.1rem;
  vertical-align: 5%;
  color: orange;
}
```

I have tried to add `transition` to `#projects-grid p:hover::after` and `#projects-grid p:hover::before` but it wouldn't work.

So, how can I target specifically those characters in `:hover::after` and `:hover::before`?

Comment: What property are you actually transitioning?

Comment: To clarify Paulie's question: you have to actually transition some CSSäproperty. You can't just transition between an element "existing" and "not existing". You have to transition a property like `opacity` or `color` or something like that (and not all props can be transitioned smoothly, some are boolean)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use a CSS property that supports gradual transitions.

**Your problem** was likely that you tried to "make a pseudo-element exist gradually" which doesn't work. (You might have been looking at some jQuery functions that sort of achieved this)

Or you used a CSS-property which doesn't support gradual transitions. (`visibility` is one example. You can set `transition:visibility 1s` but it will not work as expected - it will instantly flip from `visibility:hidden` to `visibility:visible` instead of gradually transitioning during 1 second)

**My solution** is to transition from `opacity:0` to `opacity:1`

One benefit of this is that the layout will not be jumping around on hover.

The pseudo-element has been rendered, it is taking up space but it's just not visually visible until you hover, which makes it gradually become visually visible.

```css
#projects-grid p::after {
  content: " />";
  vertical-align: baseline;
}

#projects-grid p::before {
  content: "< ";
  vertical-align: 5%;
}

#projects-grid p::before,
#projects-grid p::after {
  font-size: 1.1rem;
  color: orange;
  transition: opacity 0.3s ease;
  opacity: 0;
}

#projects-grid p:hover::after,
#projects-grid p:hover::before {
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<div id="projects-grid">
  <figure class="project-tile">
    <a href="">
      <img src="Portfolio_project_img_1.png" alt="">
      <p>Tribute Page</p>
    </a>
  </figure>
</div>
```

Sidenote: It can be tricky to find a list of CSS props that support gradual transitions. Most lists like https://www.quackit.com/css/css3/animations/animatable_properties/ include `visibility` which is kind of a lie - since it cannot gradually animate the way you expect it to, it just flips instantly from visible to invisible